# how to add parameterized message in freemarker / spring messages

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, freemarker

I'm using freemarker as view renderer in a Spring application. Is there any way to parameterise messages from the spring.ftl library?

In java we'd use the message source `getMessageSource("code.key", new String[]{"param1", "param2"}, null, null)` and it interpolates the string.

But there doesn't appear to be an option for this with `spring.messageText` or `spring.message`.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to simulate it? I know I can add in the controller, but all the other messages use the macros, and it seems like a bit of a workaround for something that should be easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freemarker can be used together with any taglibrary.
Have you tried using the Spring taglib with the "message" tag?
(<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>)

Please see following links for additional details:
http://freemarker.org/docs/pgui_misc_servlet.html#autoid_56
http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-internationalization-example/

Please let us know if this works fine..